# Create a file and getting size of said file using python

Tags: python

The create_python_script function creates a new python script in the current working directory, adds the line of comments to it declared  by the 'comments' variable, and returns the size of the new file.

```
def create_python_script(filename):
   comments = "exemple"
   with open(filename, "w") as file:
      file.write(comments)
      filesize = os.path.getsize(file)
   return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py")
```

Instead of printing the size of the file, this code produces the following error:

> TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer,
> not TextIOWrapper

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is? The print is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: `It doesn't work` This doesn't really tell us much.  Explain what the program _actually does_, and how that is different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace, not only the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "example"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return(filesize)

output = create_python_script('abc.py')
```

Close the file before checking the size.